# Unable to deploy ear which uses Hibernate 3.6 on Wildfly8.1

Tags: jboss7.x, wildfly-8

I have been trying to deploy an application which uses Hibernate 3.6, on Wildfly8.1.

My application is an EAR, which consists of a war and ejb.jar.
After trying out several other things, I found this solution which seemed promising:
https://developer.jboss.org/message/882769

As per this solution, I have specified the correct provider for hibernate 3.6 and included all the jar files needed in the lib directory, but this does not work!

I also found this link to be helpful:

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/JPA+Reference+Guide?_sscc=t#JPAReferenceGuide-PackagingtheHibernate3.5orgreater3.xJPApersistenceproviderwithyourapplication

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Please find the error in the server log below:

> ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-8) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."xyz.ear".FIRST_MODULE_USE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."xyz.ear".FIRST_MODULE_USE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase FIRST_MODULE_USE of deployment "xyz.ear"
>       at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:166) [wildfly-server-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
>       at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
>       at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
>   Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link org/hibernate/ejb/HibernatePersistence (Module "deployment.xyz.ear:main" from Service Module Loader)
>       at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:487) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
>       at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:277) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
>       at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:92) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
>       at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:568) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
>       at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:205) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
>       at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
>       at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
>       at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
>       at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
>       at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceProviderHandler.deploy(PersistenceProviderHandler.java:74)
>       at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceBeginInstallProcessor.deploy(PersistenceBeginInstallProcessor.java:49)
>       at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159) [wildfly-server-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
>       ... 5 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/spi/PersistenceProvider
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
>       at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:361) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
>       at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:482) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
>       ... 16 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider from [Module "deployment.xyz.ear:main" from Service Module Loader]
>       at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
>       at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
>       at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
>       at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
>       at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
>       ... 20 more
>
> 15:12:01,051 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014613: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("subsystem" => "jsr77")]) - failure description: {"JBAS014879: One or more services were unable to start due to one or more indirect dependencies not being available." => {
>       "Services that were unable to start:" => ["jboss.jsr77.ejb"],
>       "Services that may be the cause:" => [
>           "jboss.io.worker.default",
>           "jboss.remoting.remotingConnectorInfoService.remoting-connector",
>           "jboss.web.common.server"
>       ]
>   }}
>   15:12:01,122 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014613: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("subsystem" => "remoting")]) - failure description: {"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.remoting.endpoint.subsystem is missing [jboss.io.worker.default]"]}
>   15:12:01,135 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014613: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "xyz.ear")]) - failure description: {
>       "JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"xyz.ear\".FIRST_MODULE_USE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"xyz.ear\".FIRST_MODULE_USE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase FIRST_MODULE_USE of deployment \"xyz.ear\"
>       Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link org/hibernate/ejb/HibernatePersistence (Module \"deployment.xyz.ear:main\" from Service Module Loader)
>       Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/spi/PersistenceProvider
>       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider from [Module \"deployment.xyz.ear:main\" from Service Module Loader]"},
>       "JBAS014879: One or more services were unable to start due to one or more indirect dependencies not being available." => {
>           "Services that were unable to start:" => [
>               "jboss.deployment.subunit.\"xyz.ear\".\"xyz-ejb.jar\".FIRST_MODULE_USE",
>               "jboss.deployment.subunit.\"xyz.ear\".\"xyz.war\".FIRST_MODULE_USE"
>           ],
>           "Services that may be the cause:" => [
>               "jboss.io.worker.default",
>               "jboss.remoting.remotingConnectorInfoService.remoting-connector",
>               "jboss.web.common.server"
>           ]
>       }
>   }
>   15:12:01,436 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014613: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("subsystem" => "webservices")]) - failure description: {"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.ws.config is missing [jboss.web.common.server]"]}
>   15:12:01,450 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014613: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
>       ("subsystem" => "naming"),
>       ("service" => "remote-naming")
>   ]) - failure description: {"JBAS014879: One or more services were unable to start due to one or more indirect dependencies not being available." => {
>       "Services that were unable to start:" => ["jboss.naming.remote"],
>       "Services that may be the cause:" => [
>           "jboss.io.worker.default",
>           "jboss.remoting.remotingConnectorInfoService.remoting-connector",
>           "jboss.web.common.server"
>       ]
>   }}
>   15:12:01,940 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014613: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
>       ("subsystem" => "ejb3"),
>       ("service" => "remote")
>   ]) - failure description: {"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.ejb3.connector is missing [jboss.remoting.remotingConnectorInfoService.remoting-connector]"]}
>   15:12:02,393 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) JBAS018559: Deployed "xyz.ear" (runtime-name : "xyz.ear")
>   15:12:02,570 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Service status report
>   JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
>         service jboss.io.worker.default (missing) dependents: [service jboss.remoting.endpoint.subsystem] 
>         service jboss.remoting.remotingConnectorInfoService.remoting-connector (missing) dependents: [service jboss.ejb3.connector] 
>         service jboss.web.common.server (missing) dependents: [service jboss.ws.config] 
>   JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."xyz.ear".FIRST_MODULE_USE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."xyz.ear".FIRST_MODULE_USE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase FIRST_MODULE_USE of deployment "xyz.ear"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the application is now loading in wildfly 8.1.0.Final. We ended up upgrading Hibernate to 4.1 (packaged by default with Wildfly). And since this is the default, a 'provider' tag was not necessary. We changed, 2 XML files i.e. jboss-deployment-structure.xml & persistence.xml and a java file in the application (which consisted of ServiceLocator).